# PyGObject for Python 3.5.1?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pygobject

I am using Debian Linux, and I have the package python3-gi installed from Synaptic, and this works fine if I use my Python 3.4 interpreter. But, when I run a Gtk+3 program using 3.5, it gets stuck at the `from gi.repository import Gtk` line, saying there's no module named Gtk. Additionally, I don't *think* that pip works for Python 3.5 on my computer, although I'm not sure. I just know that `pip install PyGObject` doesn't work. Finally, when I try to use Pycharm's specific package installer (Settings/Project Interpreter), Pycharm tells me that I don't have Python packaging tools installed (and it fails to install them when I click on the prompt it gives).

I have a 64 bit computer, Python 3.5 is installed to /usr/local/bin/ and Python 3.4 is installed to /usr/bin/.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use pip, you would have to download pygobject and build it from source yourself. https://download.gnome.org/sources/pygobject/

Comment: That does not seem to be true anymore: https://mathieu.daitauha.fr/blog/2016/07/06/pip-install-pygobject/

Comment: Correct, but it is worth noting that this method simply uses their normal build system, so you can't just install it in a fresh system or something, you require all normal build dependencies.

Comment: @smerlin You should post your comment as an answer (elaborating it a little bit, I suppose) since it is the answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I got Python 3.6 up and running with GStreamer bindings etc. on my Mac OS Sierra.**

**Follow from Step 1** if you have already installed Gstreamer and its plugins and you need to bind it to your python interpreter for development.

0a- Install gstreamer from their website ...normally and then

0b- brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-libav

1- brew install gst-python --with-python3

Note however that the 'gtk' for some reason doesn't come pre-bundled so we go to step 2.

2- brew install gtk+3

And that's it, easy as **ABC...**

Attached is a test python code to make sure you got everything right [**OPTIONAL**]

```
import gi, time, sys
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstBase', '1.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstBase, Gtk, GObject

class Main:
   def __init__(self):
       Gst.init(None)
       self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
       self.audiotestsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('audiotestsrc',  'audio')
       self.pipeline.add(self.audiotestsrc)

       self.sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autoaudiosink', 'sink')
       self.pipeline.add(self.sink)
       self.audiotestsrc.link(self.sink)
       self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
       time.sleep(3)
       self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
       self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
       self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
       sys.exit(0)
start =  Main()
Gtk.main()
```

Hope er'thing works out, c ya!!